# Trying to alternate between players

Tags: python, python-3.x

this code is for a game, it has a 4 by 4 board with the function

> create_game_board(values):

with two players they can choose from 4  pieces to win the game you have to put 4 pieces in a line vertically or horizontally or diagonally, what I'm trying to do here is to alternate between two players in the function

> make_move()

but honestly, I couldn’t manage to do it if you guys have any idea to help me I will be grateful
I know the code is finished yet still need some work to d

> check_win(player_position, current_player)

check to win

> check_draw

check to draw

```
def create_game_board(values):
    print("\n")
    print("\t     |     |     |")
    print("\t  {}  |  {}  |  {}  |  {}     1 | 2 | 3 | 4".format(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]))
    print('\t_____|_____|_____|_____')

    print("\t     |     |     |")
    print("\t  {}  |  {}  |  {}  |  {}     5 | 6 | 7 | 8".format(values[4], values[5], values[6], values[7]))
    print('\t_____|_____|_____|_____')

    print("\t     |     |")

    print("\t  {}  |  {}  |  {}  |  {}     9 | 10 | 11 | 12".format(values[8], values[9], values[10], values[11]))
    print('\t_____|_____|_____|_____')

    print("\t     |     |     |")

    print("\t  {}  |  {}  |  {}  |  {}     13 | 14 | 15 | 16".format(values[12], values[13], values[14], values[15]))
    print("\t     |     |     |")

    print("\n")


def print_scoreboard(score_board):
    print("\t--------------------------------")
    print("\t              SCOREBOARD       ")
    print("\t--------------------------------")

    players = list(score_board.keys())
    print("\t   ", players[0], "\t    ", score_board[players[0]])
    print("\t   ", players[1], "\t    ", score_board[players[1]])

    print("\t--------------------------------\n")


def check_win(player_position, current_player):
    sol = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [1, 5, 9, 13], [2, 6, 10, 14], [3, 7, 11, 15],
           [4, 8, 12, 16], [1, 6, 11, 16], [4, 7, 10, 13]]
    for x in sol:
        if all(y in player_position[current_player] for y in x):
            return True
    return False


def check_draw(player_position):
    if len(player_position['A']) + len(player_position['B']) + len(player_position['C']) + len(
            player_position['D']) == 16:
        return True
    return False


def make_move(current_player):
    values = [' ' for i in range(16)]
    player_position = {'A': [], 'B': [], 'C': [], 'D': []}

    while True:
        create_game_board(values)

        try:
            print("Player ", current_player, " turn. Which box? : ", end="")
            move = int(input())
        except ValueError:
            print("Wrong Input!!! Try Again")
            continue

        if move < 1 or move > 16:
            print("Wrong Input!!! Try Again")
            continue

        if values[move - 1] != ' ':
            print("Place already filled. Try again!!")
            continue

        # Update game information
        # Updating grid status
        values[move - 1] = current_player

        # Updating player positions
        player_position[current_player].append(move)

        if check_win(player_position, current_player):
            create_game_board(values)
            print("Player ", current_player, " has won the game!!")
            print("\n")
            return current_player

        if check_draw(player_position):
            create_game_board(values)
            print("Game Drawn")
            print("\n")
            return 'L'


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Player 1")
    player1 = input("Enter the name : ")
    print("\n")

    print("Player 2")
    player2 = input("Enter the name : ")
    print("\n")

    current_player_1 = player1
    current_player_2 = player2
    # Stores the choice of players
    player_choice = {'A': "", 'B': "", 'C': "", 'D': ""}
    # Stores the options
    options = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    # Stores the scoreboard
    score_board = {player1: 0, player2: 0}
    print_scoreboard(score_board)

    while True:

        print("Turn to choose for", current_player_1)
        print("Enter 1-A, 2-B, 3-C, 4-D")
        print("Enter 5 to Quit")
        try:
            choice_1 = int(input())
        except ValueError:
            print("Wrong Input!!! Try Again\n")
            continue

        if choice_1 == 1:
            player_choice['A'] = current_player_1
        elif choice_1 == 2:
            player_choice['B'] = current_player_1
        elif choice_1 == 3:
            player_choice['C'] = current_player_1
        elif choice_1 == 4:
            player_choice['D'] = current_player_1
        elif choice_1 == 5:
            print("Final Scores")
            print_scoreboard(score_board)
            break

        print("Turn to choose for", current_player_2)
        print("Enter 1-A, 2-B, 3-C, 4-D")
        print("Enter 5 to Quit")
        try:
            choice_2 = int(input())
        except ValueError:
            print("Wrong Input!!! Try Again\n")
            continue
        if choice_2 == 1:
            player_choice['A'] = current_player_2
        elif choice_2 == 2:
            player_choice['B'] = current_player_2
        elif choice_2 == 3:
            player_choice['C'] = current_player_2
        elif choice_2 == 4:
            player_choice['D'] = current_player_2
        elif choice_2 == 5:
            print("Final Scores")
            print_scoreboard(score_board)
            break

        winner_1 = make_move(options[choice_1 - 1])
        winner_2 = make_move(options[choice_2 - 1])

        # Edits the scoreboard according to the winner
        if winner_1 != 'L' and winner_2 != 'L':
            player_won = player_choice[winner_1] or player_choice[winner_2]
            score_board[player_won] = score_board[player_won] + 1

        print_scoreboard(score_board)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're calling your own `make_move` function correctly.  In your `__main__` block where you have:

```
print("Turn to choose for", current_player_1)
```

it seems like you should be doing:

```
make_move(player_1)
```

i.e. calling `make_move` with the current player (which in this part of the loop is `player_1` -- I'm not sure what the point of `current_player_1` is).

Comment: make_move function is not complete I'm trying to alternate between players in it that's my idea...  if you have another way to alternate between players I'll be grateful @Samwise

Comment: TBH I can't even figure out how the game is supposed to work.  Your explanation didn't include any examples, and the code doesn't have any useful comments.  If you google something like "python tic tac toe" I'm sure you can find examples of people implementing simple 2-player games in Python and borrow some ideas from there.

Comment: it is game for 2 players each player can choose from 4 different pieces and place them in the board the winning when you got 4 pieces in a line horizontally vertically or diagonally like tic tac toe

Comment: existing tic-tac-toe implementations should be a good model to follow then!